# SOMATÓRIO EM UMA COLUNA EM UM INTERVALO DE LINHAS

Tags: r

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Tenho o seguinte banco de dados:
Gostaria de somar a INTE_C1 para cada mês.

Ou seja, pra janeiro somar do 1/1/2000 até 1/31/2000...

Comment: Bem-vinda ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Answer (score 1):

Você também pode usar o pacote `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
summary <-  dados %>%
                  mutate (Date = as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y"),
                          Mes = as.Date(Date, "%Y%m")) %>%
                 group_by (Mes) %>%
                 summarise (Soma = sum (INTE_C1, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
                 ungroup ()
```

Caso queria aplicar isso para todas colunas você pode fazer da seguinte forma

```
summary <-  dados %>%
                  mutate (Date = as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y"),
                          Mes = as.Date(Date, "%Y%m")) %>%
                 group_by (Mes) %>%
                 summarise_at (vars(INTE_C1:SO2), sum, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
                 ungroup ()
```

Se previsar de mais funcoes pode utilizar o seguinte:

```
summary <-  dados %>%
                  mutate (Date = as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y"),
                          Mes = as.Date(Date, "%Y%m")) %>%
                 group_by (Mes) %>%
                 summarise_at (vars(INTE_C1:SO2), list (sum, mean, sd), na.rm = TRUE) %>%
                 ungroup ()
```

Uma outra sugestão é utilizar trabalhar os dados no formato longo da seguinte forma:

```
library (tidyr)
summary <-  dados %>%
                  mutate (Date = as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y"),
                          Mes = as.Date(Date, "%Y%m")) %>%
                 gather (key = "Parametro", value = "Resultado", INTE_C1:SO2) %>% 
                 group_by (Mes, Parametro) %>%
                 summarise (Soma =  sum(Resultado, na.rm = TRUE),
                            Media =  mean(Resultado, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
                 ungroup ()
```

Comment: no formato longo é mais fácil trabalhar os dados, criar loops etc

Answer (score 0):

Aqui vão duas maneiras de agregar uma coluna por mês.

Primeiro tem que transformar a coluna `Date` em verdadeira data.

```
dados$Date <- as.Date(dados$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Agora, somar a coluna `INTE_C1` com `aggregate`.

Só com R base, o `format` cria um vetor de classe `"character"` com ano e mês.

```
mes <- format(dados$Date, "%Y-%m")
aggregate(INTE_C1 ~ mes, dados, sum)
```

Com o pacote `zoo`, também se obtém um vetor com ano e mês, de classe `"yearmon"` (year month).

```
mes <- zoo::as.yearmon(dados$Date)
aggregate(INTE_C1 ~ mes, dados, sum)
```

### Código para criar os dados de teste.

```
set.seed(1234)

Date <- seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), Sys.Date(), by = "day")
Date <- format(Date, "%m/%d/%Y")
INTE_C1 <- sample(20, length(Date), TRUE)
dados <- data.frame(Date, INTE_C1)
```